# Error Code 415 with retrofit

Tags: kotlin, retrofit, mvp, android-mvp

I have created following API class to query the web service

```
 @POST("/v1/User/forgot-password")
    @FormUrlEncoded
    fun forgotPass(@Field("email") email: String): Call<ForgotPassword>
```

and called it as

```
 val call = RetrofitHelper.instance!!.api.forgotPass(email)
        call.enqueue(object : Callback<ForgotPassword> {

            override fun onResponse(call: Call<ForgotPassword>, response: Response<ForgotPassword>) {
                if (response.code() == 200) {
                    Log.e("response", response.body().toString())
                    forgotPassView.forgotPassRequestSuccess()

                }
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<ForgotPassword>, t: Throwable) {
                Log.e("onFailure", t.message)
            }
        })
```

The response I am getting is `415`, while web services are working fine.

I have tried different techniques to resolve it but it seems there are something more to it. 
Please help me solve this issue.
Thanks.

Comment: Should be `"v1/User/forgot-password"` and `baseUrl("blahblah/")` with emphasis on that `/` missing from the first, and there on the second

Comment: A 415 usually means you are sending your data in the wrong format.  Are you sure the service is expecting the data as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` vs some other format (JSON, query parameter in the url, etc)?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce it did not made any difference

Comment: @iagreen yeah it was application/json

Comment: But I am still getting 400 `HttpLoggingInterceptor` doesnt show anything

Comment: So your api is expecting something like `{ email : "me@email.com" }` as the POST body?

Comment: @iagreen yes exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send a json payload, define a wrapper class --

```
data class EmailBody(val email: String)
```

and use that as the `@Body` for your `POST`

```
@POST("v1/User/forgot-password")
fun forgotPass(@Body email: EmailBody): Call<Void>
```

Then, when you want to call it, wrap the email address in an `EmailBody` object --

```
service.forgotPass(EmailBody(email))
```

Comment: things moved, but now I am getting onFailure

Comment: `End of input at line 1 column 1 path $`

Comment: What is the server sending back?  It sounds like it is sending back nothing at all.  From your code above it looks like you are expecting an object back?

Comment: the server will returns nothing. just code 200 or other

Comment: Ah, then you shouldn't be trying to parse the body as `ForgotPassword`.  Use `Void` instead. See the edit above.

Comment: Worked! Perfectly! Thanks!